# javascriptとjsonを用いて要素を表示させたい

Tags: javascript, json

これらのコードをhtmlで読み込み`<div id="gallery"></div>`の部分で読み込みたいと思っています。

しかし、実際には何も表示されない状況です。bootstrapを用いて並べるようにしています。どのように対処すればいいのでしょうか？

javascript

```
    $(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#gallery').each(function () {

    var $container = $(this),
        $loadMoreButton = $('#load-more'), // 追加ボタン
        addItemCount = 16,                 // 一度に表示するアイテム数
        addedd = 0,                        // 表示済みのアイテム数
        allData = [];                      // すべての JSON データ



    // JSON を取得し、initGallery 関数を実行
    $.getJSON('./data/content.json', initGallery);

    // ギャラリーを初期化する
    function initGallery (data) {

        // 取得した JSON データを格納
        allData = data;

        // 最初のアイテムを表示
        addItems();

        // 追加ボタンがクリックされたら追加で表示
        $loadMoreButton.on('click', addItems);
    }

    // アイテムを生成しドキュメントに挿入する
    function addItems () {

        var elements = [],
            // 追加するデータの配列
            slicedData = allData.slice(addedd, addedd + addItemCount);

        // slicedData の要素ごとに DOM 要素を生成
        $.each(slicedData, function (i, item) {
            var itemHTML =
                '<div class="col-sm-6">'+
                    '<h4>' + item.title + '</h4>'+
                        '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-' + item.aspect + '">' +
                            '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="' + item.url + '"></iframe>' +
                        '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            elements.push($(itemHTML).get(0));
        });

        // DOM 要素の配列をコンテナーに挿入
        $container.append(elements);

        // 追加済みアイテム数の更新
        addedd += slicedData.length;

        // JSON データがすべて追加し終わっていたら追加ボタンを消す
        if (addedd < allData.length) {
            $loadMoreButton.show();
        } else {
            $loadMoreButton.hide();
        }
    }
    });
    });
```

json
// JSON Document

```
    [
    {
    "title": "タイトル",
    "aspect": "16by9",
    "url": "youtubeのURL"
    },
    {
    "title": "タイトル",
    "aspect": "16by9",
    "url": "youtubeのURL"
    },
    {・・・・}
    ]
```

Comment: console にエラーメッセージは出ていないでしょうか？回答するインは情報が足りないと考えます。もしかして、`./data/content.json` が失敗しているのでは？

Comment: consoleには何のエラーも表示されていません。また、content.jsonへのリンクも間違っていないことは確認しています。

Comment: 質問欄のコードを検証してみましたが、特に問題は無いようです。実際に受け取っているJSONの中身を開発者ツールで確認してみてください。https://jsfiddle.net/y0de0u4v/1/